# Web Request Get Response fails on second try

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, getresponse

I wrote a program that searches for a user name on a web site and downloads the their main html page, finds the link to the next page and downloads that and so on. When I run the program the first time the get response for the search works correctly and the get response for downloading all of html pages works correctly. However, when I do a second search the get response fails for the search. I thought that maybe it was the server only allowing so many searches in a time period but it isn't that. When I close my program and run it again everything works fine again. Why does the get response fail on any attempts besides the initial one? You can't define a web request as new and their seems to be no way of closing a web request once it gets a response to free up resources. Is it because I run the whole process in a background worker? I don't know what's wrong. I always could do as many searches as I wanted to just yesterday...

Here's my code for the search form:

```
Private Sub FormSearch_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'if the user name is empty then initialize it
    If My.Settings.UserName = "" Then
        My.Settings.UserName = ""
    End If
    'if the current url is empty then initialize it
    If My.Settings.CurrentURL = "" Then
        My.Settings.CurrentURL = ""
    End If
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxUserName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxUserName.TextChanged
    'if the text length of the text box is greater then zero
    If TextBoxUserName.TextLength > 0 Then
        'enable the search button
        ButtonSearch.Enabled = True
    Else
        'disable the search button and set focus on the text box
        ButtonSearch.Enabled = False
        TextBoxUserName.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSearch.Click
    'trim the text box of any spaces
    My.Settings.UserName = Trim(TextBoxUserName.Text)
    'if the user name is not equal to null
    If My.Settings.UserName <> "" Then
        'set the current url and test if it exists
        My.Settings.CurrentURL = "*url here*"
        If URLExists(My.Settings.CurrentURL) = True Then
            'save the settings
            My.Settings.Save()
            'return ok for the dialog result and close the form
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
            Me.Close()
        Else 'cannot find the account
            'set the text box text to null and set focus on it
            TextBoxUserName.Text = ""
            TextBoxUserName.Focus()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    'create a new uri
    Dim uriURL As New Uri(url)
    'create a new web request of the uri
    Dim wrRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uriURL)
    'set the web request timeout and method
    wrRequest.Timeout = 30000
    wrRequest.Method = "GET"
    'create a new web response
    Dim wrResponse As WebResponse
    Try
        'if the response succeeds then return true
        wrResponse = wrRequest.GetResponse
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception 'the response failed so return false
        LabelMessage.Text = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You need to show your code so we can see what is happening

Comment: The problem was I wasn't closing the http web response. Now it works fine.